# Call stored procedures in Oracle from C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, stored-procedures

I have a page with a textbox that passed a value through a stored procedure in Oracle. the procedure got changed so, there are now 2 parameters, one for the input value and a second one that returns an integer value back.

Here is the Oracle procedure:

```
procedure UnoxDataFix(p_shpmt_nbr in pkms.asn_hdr.shpmt_nbr%type, retval out integer) is
  begin
  retval:=0;
    for r in (
        -- simple select statement
        )
    loop    
     if(r.stat_code = 10 and r.whse_xfer_flag = 'Y')
     then     
        update pkms.asn_dtl ad 
          -- simple set statement
        update pkms.asn_hdr ah
          -- simple set statement
          where ah.shpmt_nbr = p_shpmt_nbr
           RETURNING 1 into retval;
        commit;   
      end if;    
    end loop;
  end;
```

And here is the core C# code I had:

```
this.oraServer.ExecuteNonQuery(this.connectionString, CommandType.Text, "begin INTEGRATION.UnoxDataFix('" + input + "'); end;");
```

The connection string works. It's just the actual procedure that is giving the error. The 'input' value is the actual value that is sent to the procedure. But for returning the 'retval' back to the site, I'm not sure how to. I have tried Googling what I can, but it doesn't help.
I'm a little slow, so all comments are most welcome. :)

Comment: See [related SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6883362/175679). Get rid of the begin/end statements. Only the function name should be present in the **CommandText**. You need to add the parameters separate from the **CommandText**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the procedure now expects 2 parameters, you need to give 2 parameters and not only the input parameter. 
Also, I prefer to use bind variables to prevent sql injection. (Yes, you can also use a bind variable for the OUT parameter).

```
begin INTEGRATION.UnoxDataFix(:input, :retval); end;
```

I am not familiar with the specifics of C#, so I can't help you with the exact methods to use to insert and retrieve the values.

On a side note, what kind of naming convention is this? Are you aiming for unreadability? :)

> pkms.asn_hdr.shpmt_nbr

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I can use bind variables, but that doesn't help me on C#'s specific on how to get the return value from the procedure.

"On a side note, what kind of naming convention is this? Are you aiming for unreadability? :)" Yeah, I know what you mean, the names hard to read :)